Cython: indexing typed memoryviews of a class attribute without interacting with python
I have a code such as
import numpy as np

cdef class A:
    cdef float[:] x

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.arange(10)

    @cython.boundscheck(False)  # turn off bounds-checking for entire function
    @cython.wraparound(False)
    @cython.cdivision(True)     # turn off checking for division by zero
    def func(self):
        cdef Py_ssize_t i

        for i in range(10):
            self.x[i]


I want the indexing self.x[i] to be done completely in C but it keeps interacting with python and I don't know why. If I change the code like the following,
import numpy as np

cdef class A:
    cdef float[:] x

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.arange(10)

    @cython.boundscheck(False)  # turn off bounds-checking for entire function
    @cython.wraparound(False)
    @cython.cdivision(True)     # turn off checking for division by zero
    def func(self):
        cdef Py_ssize_t i
        cdef float[:] x

        x = self.x
        for i in range(10):
            x[i]


then the indexing x[i] is doesn't interact with python. How can I directly index self.x without interacting with python?

You want the directive
@cython.initializedcheck(False)

to skip the check.
Of course you need to be certain that you have initialized it, so don't copy-paste the check everywhere without thinking. (This applies to boundcheck, wraparound and cdivision too).

Thanks for the answer:) Works perfectly!
